# how to reduce woocommerce price (total price including taxes) with a gift card code

Tags: php, wordpress

i created a gift card that a user can purchase, then receive a code by email. this code can then be redeemed as cash value on a product of their choice. the issue i am having is when the user redeems the code on the checkout page, the amount from the gift card is reduced before the taxes are calculated. ex: gc value: 10$. product is: 100$ and tax is: 5%. it should be (product + tax) - gc. but instead i am getting (product -gc) + tax. from what i found, i need to use the gc as a fee to acquire what i want, but its not working.

```
function tcms_add_gift_card_field() {
    echo '<div id="tcms_gift_card_field"><h2>' . __('Gift Card') . '</h2>';
    woocommerce_form_field('tcms_gift_card_code', array(
            'type'          => 'text',
            'class'         => array('tcms-gift-card-code-field form-row-wide'),
            'label'         => __('Gift Card Code'),
            'placeholder'   => __('Enter your gift card code here'),
    ), '');
    echo '<button type="button" class="button" id="apply_gift_card_button">' . __('Apply Gift Card') . '</button>';
    echo '<div id="gift_card_message"></div>';
    echo '</div>';
}
add_action('woocommerce_after_checkout_billing_form', 'tcms_add_gift_card_field');


function tcms_apply_gift_card_ajax_handler() {
    if ( ! isset( $_POST['gift_card_code'] ) || empty( $_POST['gift_card_code'] ) ) {
            wp_send_json_error( 'No gift card code provided' );
            return;
    }

    $gift_card_code = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['gift_card_code'] );
    $gift_card_details = get_gift_card_details($gift_card_code);

    if (!$gift_card_details || $gift_card_details->current_value <= 0) {
            wp_send_json_error('Invalid gift card code or no balance');
            return;
    }

    // Set session variables without directly manipulating the cart here
    WC()->session->set('gift_card_code', $gift_card_code);
    WC()->session->set('gift_card_amount', $gift_card_details->current_value);

    wp_send_json_success(array(
            'message' => 'Gift card applied successfully',
            // Optionally, you can send back the current total for immediate UI update
            // 'new_order_total' => WC()->cart->get_total()
    ));
}
add_action('wp_ajax_tcms_apply_gift_card', 'tcms_apply_gift_card_ajax_handler');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_tcms_apply_gift_card', 'tcms_apply_gift_card_ajax_handler');

function get_gift_card_details($gift_card_code) {
  global $wpdb;
  $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'tcms_gift_cards';
  return $wpdb->get_row($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM {$table_name} WHERE gift_card_code = %s AND status = 'active'", $gift_card_code));
}

function apply_gift_card_discount_as_fee($cart) {
    if (!is_cart()) return; // Apply only on the cart page

    $gift_card_amount = WC()->session->get('gift_card_amount', 0);
    if ($gift_card_amount <= 0) {
            return;
    }

    $total_cart_amount = $cart->get_subtotal() + $cart->get_subtotal_tax();
    $discount = min($gift_card_amount, $total_cart_amount);

    error_log('the total price is: ' . $total_cart_amount);
    error_log('the total discount is: ' . $discount);


    $cart->add_fee(__('Gift Card Discount'), -$discount, false);

    WC()->session->set('gift_card_amount', $gift_card_amount - $discount);
}
add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'apply_gift_card_discount_as_fee', 20, 1);
```